# Google charts visualization: Timeline - full timestamp

Tags: google-visualization, visualization

Is there a way the hover state to show the full timestamp including year, month, day, hour and min? Something like **2013-Oct-06 13:32**

At the moment the hover state shows different parts of the timestamp depending on the resolution of the graph.

Here are the docs for the visualization:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

Comment: Formatting the time in the tooltips is not (yet?) supported in the Timelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to think of workaround of this limitation.

What I did is to place the time string formatted exactly as I wanted to be as the **bar label** for the time period. Since the bar label is present on the first row of the tool-tip, this solves the issue very nicely.